# string interpolation has red parenthesis instead of black in swift

Tags: swift

I am working on a map application that allows you to place a pin on the map and the address is suppose to appear when you click it. The problem is that when I assign the pin a location (subThoroughfare and thoroughfare) using string interpolation, the parenthesis around these variables show up red instead of black. When I run the app there is no error but the address doesn't show up when you click the pin. I never had this problem before the last update, does anyone know what this means or can tell me what is going on?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Looks like swift changed their formatting when you use string interpolation(the parenthesis for \(subThoroughfare) are red instead of black now). I was missing a line of code and that is why the address wouldn't appear. Sorry for the inconvenience.